# Rendering artifacts in orthogonal views

Tags: 3d-view, artifacts

In 3D Viewport when I set the view to orthogonal the background grid goes all wonky. See images below. Obviously i'd prefer this not to happen, for the grid to render like a proper grid. Any guidance on this issue?

Thanks, JK.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm quite sure this is some sort of graphics driver issue, cannot reproduce that here. What GPU are you on?

Comment: CPU based on Mac. OS ver: 10.14 (18A391)

Comment: I suspect that is the culprit here - sorry I can't help with OSX :-/